# Weird problem with cisco SGE2000 switch

Tags: cisco, switch

I have a CISCO SGE2000 in standalone mode with other 4 switches (not CISCO) connected to it   through optical links. I setted the ipv4 address on SGE2000 and the admin password. It works without any problem but sumetimes and suddenly It seems to reset itself. In other words the ipv4 is resetted to factory default a the password too. I can't understand why?
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're forgetting to write the config back then that sounds properly broken, have you asked Cisco themselves? I think you need to as I think you may have dead flash or something on the actual switch sorry.

Comment: I found this on google. Could be the solution?

Comment: you need to do the following steps to permanently save your settings
 
go to Admin > File Management > Copy Files
click on Copy Configuration button
set Source File Name as Running Config
set Destination File Name as Startup Config
click Apply

Comment: ah yes, so you weren't writing your config back - you're not the first person to make that mistake and won't be the last - glad you're sorted.